# Gmail dark mode

Tags: gmail, mac

Is there a way to read the body of an email (in Gmail) in dark mode? I am not referring to Gmail themes, where it makes the background dark, but want the body of all emails dark. My eyes get strained reading emails in light mode. By the way, I want this on my Mac desktop. My iPhone has this feature already.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What web browser are you using? What have you tried so far? Also please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi, I use Chrome and Brave browsers.  I searched for browser extensions, but am unable to find any which provides dark mode for the body of the emails.

Answer (score 0):

Some browser allow Dark Mode with an auto detection and change, but they use this functionality as a flag, because it's "beta" and not perfectly implemented (but if you want to try, view this [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/446198/how-to-force-dark-mode-on-every-website-in-google-chrome/) for Chrome).
Otherwise, you can try with [this userstyle](https://github.com/thiagobraga/gmail-userstyles), but you need to use it with [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) (a Chrome extension that allow custom styles).